# Javafx: ListView disable a specified element of the list

Tags: java, listview, javafx, javafx-8

I have a `ListView<String>` and I want to disable one specified element of the list, to become unselectable for the user. Is there a way to disable just one specified element for selection?

Comment: By "disable" you mean not being able to select it?

Comment: Yup, and to be marked gray(if it's possible) as If i disable a `Button`.

Comment: Call [setDisable](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/Node.html#disableProperty) on the cell?

Comment: I tried this but it there is no setDisable method for an item.

Comment: I tried this way: listView.getItems().get(3).   <- and there isn't any method for disabling.

Comment: You're supposed to disable the [cell](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/control/ListCell.html), not the item. The item is a generic type, it can be an `Integer`; it makes no sense to disable a number.

Comment: Might help you: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20936101/get-listcell-via-listview

Comment: But how can I access the cells of the listView?

Comment: I just gave you the link.

Comment: Use a cell factory and enable/disable the cell in the cell's `updateItem` method

Comment: It's working fine thanks for the answers.

Comment: @Sunflame When you get enough reputation you might wish to [self-answer your question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Thanks to @user1803551 and @James_D i could solve the problem, here is the sollution:

```
listView.setCellFactory(new Callback<ListView<String>, ListCell<String>>() {
        @Override 
        public ListCell<String> call(ListView<String> param) {
            return new ListCell<String>() {
                @Override 
                protected void updateItem(String item, boolean empty) {
                    super.updateItem(item, empty);
                    if ("Orange".equals(item)) {
                        setDisable(true);
                    } else {
                        setDisable(false);
                    }
                    setText(item);
                }

            };
        }
    });
```

Comment: This disables the item, however the list item can still be focused using the keyboard. How do you prevent that from happening?

Comment: `setFocusTraversable(false)`

Comment: Tried it, but it doesn't work while using the arrow keys on the list. Also, the documentation specifies that `setFocusTraversable` is for the Tab key.