# JavaFx: invalidate ChangeListener

Tags: java, listview, javafx, javafx-8, changelistener

I have a `ListView` and it has a `ChangeListener` added to its `selectedItemProperty()`. It is possible somehow to invalidate the listener if inside the listener some condition is truefor example:

```
listView.getSelectionModel().selectedItemProperty().addListener(
            (observable, oldValue, newValue) -> {
                if (thereIsUnsavedData()) {
                    // invalidate somehow so to don't change from item A to B 
                } else{
                    // load the content of the newValue
                }
            });
```

I could make that do do nothing when the condition is true, but still changes the selection in `listView`, and that is not the sollution to listView.getSelectionModel().select(oldValue); because it trigers again the listener.Any idea?

Edit:

So I see there are some misunderstandings, so lets clarify them:

When the user clicks on another element in the `listView` that is not the current and on the current view are unsaved data, then a `Dialog` pops up and asks the user: *There are unsaved data do you wish to continue?* with **Yes / No** answers. If the user chose **Yes** then everything is fine, **let him change the view**, but if he chose **No** then the actual view should be kept. So any suggestion to disable the elements is wrong in my case. I found a solution here it is but I'm not sure about it is optimal or not:

```
private ChangeListener<Item> changeListener =
        (observable, oldValue, newValue) -> {
            if (thereAreUnsavedData()) {
                listView.getSelectionModel().selectedItemProperty().removeListener(getListener());
                Platform.runLater(() -> {
                    listView.getSelectionModel().select(oldValue);
                    listView.getSelectionModel().selectedItemProperty().addListener(getListener());
                });
            } else {
                loadSelected(newValue);
            }
        };
```

Comment: Considering SelectionModel.selectedItem is a [read only property](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/control/SelectionModel.html#selectedItemProperty), I don’t think you can affect its value.  Also, be aware that changing the behavior of a standard control can make users frustrated.

Comment: I don't want to change its value, just stop changing from an item to another if a condition is true as you can see in the question.

Comment: You could also write your own `SelectionModel` for making it impossible to select "unsave data"

Comment: I have edited the question so take a look at the edit part. And there is not selected any unsaved data, the unsaved data is already there.

Answer (score 0):

So, there are two solutions i would not recommend:

- Use `listView.getSelectionModel().select(oldValue);` to set it to the old value,  but unregister the listener before and register it back afterwards.
- Alternativley also use `listView.getSelectionModel().select(oldValue);` but set a flag that you check when it triggers the listener again.

Both solutions are error-prone.

Hence, the solution I would recommend is hindering the user to make a selection that currently does not make sense, by either removing  or better deactivating the item in the list. This would improve the Usability of your application, as the users would not be frustrated when their selection is undone.

Comment: I have made something similar that you mentioned in the first point, so I remove the listener before `.select()` and add it back again. I have `Dialog` with a message something like: The data was not saved do you wish to continue? with Yes/No answers, and if the user hits No then I want to don't change the selection in the listView.

Comment: But I think there should be a better solution to this.

Comment: So, from a Usability perspective, if the selection does not make sense, i would deactivate the item. Check for example [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43998613/javafx-listview-disable-a-specified-element-of-the-list) for how to achieve this. 

If the selection leads to a change, where some data is lost, you mind want to remember the data in the background, and when the user returns to the previous selection use this remebered data again. 

As I said, you might want to overthink your user interface design.

Comment: @Sunflame As mik suggests, disable the list cell containing the item if selecting that item is not valid. You can do this with a cell factory, though it might be a little complex. Another possible approach, which is a lot of work, is to use a custom selection model that simply doesn't allow selection of the invalid items. You need to implement `SelectionModel` from scratch to do that.

Comment: Maybe i was wrong in the question so as I mentioned in first comment I have a Dialog, that opens if the data was not saved, and if the user chose that he won't continue, so he remains in that _view_ so, he can save the data. But if he says I don't want to save it just change to another view, he can do it, so disabling all items if there is unsaved data is not the solution.

Comment: This was my second suggestion: Why not remember the state of this view and when the user changes back to this view, just repopulate it with the rembered data. Alternativley, auto-save the data when the view is changed, which for dialogs of this this kind often is the expected behaviour.